# Trying to store data into a DB from a form using php

Tags: php, mysql

Hey and thanks in advance, I'm trying to get data from a form and enter it into a database. I'm following a guide on how to do this, but the guide doesnt account for anything not working........

I've only just started out with PHP so my skills are quite limited, however I do understand all code I have written, it just doesn't work! The php script will not move past the if statement below and I can't figure out why:

```
// Check for existing user with the new id
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sessions.users WHERE userid = '$_POST[newid]'";
$result = mysqli_query($cxn, $sql);
if (!$result) {
error('A database error occurred in processing your '.
'submission.\nIf this error persists, please '.
'contact you@example.com. This is from error 1');
```

Entire code:

signup.php

```
<?php //signup.php
        include 'common.php';
        include 'db.php';

        if(!isset($_POST['submitok'])):
        // display user signup form

        ?>


    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
      <title>New User Registration</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    </head>
    <body>
      <h3>New User Registration Form</h3>
      <p><font color="orangered" size="+1"><tt><b>*</b></tt></font> indicates a required field</p>
      <form method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5">
          <tr>
            <td align="right">
              <p>User ID</p>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input name="newid" type="text" maxlength="100" size="25" />
             <font color="orangered" size="+1"><tt><b>*</b></tt></font>
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right">
            <p>Full Name</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="newname" type="text" maxlength="100" size="25" />
            <font color="orangered" size="+1"><tt><b>*</b></tt></font>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right">
            <p>E-Mail Address</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="newemail" type="text" maxlength="100" size="25" />
            <font color="orangered" size="+1"><tt><b>*</b></tt></font>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
          <td align="right">
            <p>Other Notes</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <textarea wrap="soft" name="newnotes" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right" colspan="2">
            <hr noshade="noshade" />
            <input type="reset" value="Reset Form" />
            <input type="submit" name="submitok" value="   OK   " />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
        else:
            //process sign up submission
            dbConnect('sessions');

            if ($_POST['newid']=='' or $_POST['newname']==''
          or $_POST['newemail']=='') {
            error('One or more required fields were left blank.\\n'.
                  'Please fill them in and try again.');
        }

         // Check for existing user with the new id
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sessions.users WHERE userid = '$_POST[newid]'";
        $result = mysqli_query($cxn, $sql);
        if (!$result) {
        error('A database error occurred in processing your '.
        'submission.\nIf this error persists, please '.
        'contact you@example.com. This is from error 1');
    }

        if (@mysqli_result($result,0,0)>0) {
        error('A user already exists with your chosen userid.\n'.
        'Please try another.');
        }

        $newpass = substr(md5(time()),0,6);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO sessions.users SET
        userid = '$_POST[newid]',
        password = PASSWORD('$newpass'),
        fullname = '$_POST[newname]',
        email = '$_POST[newemail]',
        notes = '$_POST[newnotes]'";
        if (!mysqli_query($sql))
        error('A database error occurred in processing your '.
        'submission.\nIf this error persists, please '.
        'contact you@example.com. This is from error 2');

        // Email the new password to the person.
        $message = "G'Day!

        Your personal account for the Project Web Site
        has been created! To log in, proceed to the
        following address:

            http://www.example.com/

        Your personal login ID and password are as
        follows:

            userid: $_POST[newid]
            password: $newpass

        You aren't stuck with this password! Your can
        change it at any time after you have logged in.

        If you have any problems, feel free to contact me at
        <you@example.com>.

        -Your Name
         Your Site Webmaster
        ";

        mail($_POST['newemail'],"Your Password for the Project Website",
            $message, "From:Your Name <you@example.com>");
        ?>

        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C/DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
          <title> Registration Complete </title>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
            content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        </head>
        <body>
        <p><strong>User registration successful!</strong></p>
        <p>Your userid and password have been emailed to
           <strong><?=$_POST['newemail']?></strong>, the email address
           you just provided in your registration form. To log in,
           click <a href="index.php">here</a> to return to the login
           page, and enter your new personal userid and password.</p>
        </body>
        </html>
        <?php
        endif;
        ?>
```

db.php

```
<?php // db.php

    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';

    function dbConnect($db='') {
        global $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass;

        $cxn = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);

        mysqli_select_db($cxn,$db)
        or die ("Couldn’t select database.");


        return $cxn;
    }   
    ?>
```

common.php

```
<?php // common.php

    function error($msg) {
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
      <script language="JavaScript">
      <!--
      alert("<?=$msg?>");
      history.back();
      //-->
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    exit;
    }
    ?>
```

Any help as to why this if statement ALWAYS produces the error would be grand - thank you.

Comment: If you're getting an error, you should include the error in your question

Comment: Sorry my wording was a little off, the php script wont move past:

    // Check for existing user with the new id
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sessions.users WHERE userid = '$_POST[newid]'";
$result = mysqli_query($cxn, $sql);
if (!$result) {
error('A database error occurred in processing your '.
'submission.\nIf this error persists, please '.
'contact you@example.com. This is from error 1');

Answer (score 0):

You're not assigning your db connection within a usable scope.  You *are* returning it from your `dbConnect()` function, you're just not doing anything with the returned value.

`dbConnect('sessions');` should be `$cxn = dbConnect('sessions');`

You would be alerted to the cause of the problem if you used [mysqli_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to let MySQL tell you what it didn't like.

Finally, you should be using bound parameters in your query instead of injecting user-provided data directly. Search something like "mysqli bound parameters" to learn how to do this.  What you have now is open to attack.

For your `INSERT` statement, use bound parameters:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO sessions.users (userid, password, fullname, email, notes) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'issss', $newID, PASSWORD($newpass), $fullName, $email, $notes);

if(!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))
{
    // use this for debugging, but do NOT leave it in production code
    die(mysqli_error($cxn));
}

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

Above is untested so it's possible you'll have to make small adjustments. It should give you a pretty good idea of what to do at least.

Also, make sure that [PASSWORD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password) is really what you want to be using. I have a feeling it's not, but I don't want to assume.

Comment: This worked thank you!! However, nothing gets added to the database now I used the INSERT instructions from the response below, so now I actually get past that IF statement but nothing happens.

Comment: That answer appears to be missing a space between the closing `)` of the fields list and the `VALUES` keyword. Here, again though, would be a good place to make use of mysql's own error reporting.

Comment: Sorry to be an absolute pain, could you give me an example of how I'd use that?

You are literally my hero! Thanks Patrick!